# Explain why we should not choose primes p and q that are too close together to form the modulus n in RSA cryptosystem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

For this question, I am trying to show that using a pair of primes p and q = p + 2 would be bad for RSA cryptosystem using Fermat's factorization method. I am new to this subject so any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

$$n = pq \tag{1}$$
$n$ is known $p$ and $q$ are not.

Let $p = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor - d  \:and \: q = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor + e\tag{2}$
$d$ and $e$ are unknown, $ \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ is easily calculated.

$$n = ({\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor -d})({\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor +e}) = {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}^2 + {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}(e - d) -ed \tag{3}$$

If $p,q$ are very close then $ed < \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor $ then $(e-d) = \frac{n - {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}^2}{{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}}$, integer division.

With $(e-d)$ calculated $ed$ then $e$ and $d$ can be calculated.

If $ed > {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}$ by a small factor then a small number of trials $k$ (i.e. millions or billions) could be tried with  $e-d = \frac{n - {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}^2}{{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}} - k \tag{4}$

Again solving for $e$ and $d$ and thus $p$ and $q$ ,see $(2)$.

Comment: thank you, with the fact that q = p + 2, would the answer be simpler than this?

Comment: When searching for large primes to use to make $n = pq$ you have to be aware of this attack in order to randomize the search for the second prime rather than continue searching from the last prime you find. And test for this attack before accepting the primes that are found.

Answer (score 0):

$$ p(p+2) = p^2 + 2p = (p+1)^2 - 1  $$

Fermat's method is to test the squares just above the target number, then see if the difference is a square... For twin primes, the very first square tried gives the answer

Comment: More generally, $p(p+2k)=(p+k)^2-k^2$ so if $k$ is small then Fermat will get the answer fast.

Comment: thank you for your reply, can you explain more about the "difference is a square part" please.

Comment: Given $n$ to be factored, you try to find $x>n$ such that the difference $x^2-n$ is a square. If you have $x^2-n=y^2$, then $n=x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ and there's your factorization, warmsoda.

Comment: Understood, warmsoda?

Comment: Please, warmsoda, do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is known to be the product of a pair of twin primes ($p$ and $p+2$), than $$n=p(p+2)= p^2+2p = (p+1)^2 +1$$

Given $n$ we just compute $p=\sqrt{n-1}-1$ (standard real number square root, easily found) and have our factors $p, p+2$.

The system would be broken in a single, easy step. Other answers have already explained the link to Fermat's method.